# Vegalite - Duplicated labels on X axis

Tags: formatting, axis

I am creating a PBI custom visual using Deneb Vegalite and I am facing problem with X axis labels.
Visual is shown in the attched image.

[image]

On X axis, I have Date type column names Date_Roadmap which I have formatted to show in month-year format.
On Y axis, I am showing release names
As marks I am showing milestones for those releases.

Problem - Today, visual generating as many labels on X axis as many marks/Milesotnes in dataset I have in that month.
However, I would like to show marks based dates at same positions but on X axis, I would like to show unique labels for Month-Year.

I would like to show marks based dates at same positions but on X axis, I would like to show unique labels for Month-Year.

Expected Output:
[image]

[Sample PBIx](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mQAc8jI6MRVk1ZYkzQ6ApVzUGaM_i2L1/view?usp=drive_link)

I have tried with different format but its not working for me.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "background": "white",
  "width": 900,
  "height": {"step": 38},
  "config": {
    "line": {"strokeWidth": 1}
  },
  "data": {"name": "dataset"},
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": "line",
      "encoding": {
        "detail": {
          "field": "Parents Release_Final",
          "type": "nominal"
        },
        "color": {"value": "#118DFF"}
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "point",
        "opacity": 1,
        "tooltip": true,
        "filled": true,
        "size": 150,
        "strokeWidth": 2
      },
      "encoding": {
        "color": {
          "field": "Milestone",
          "type": "nominal",
          "scale": {
            "domain": [
              "C1",
              "C2",
              "C3",
              "C4",
              "C5",
              "CT",
              "CP",
              "C6",
              "C7",
              "C8",
              "C9",
              "C10",
              "CCD"
            ],
            "range": [
              "#005AFF",
              "#005AFF",
              "#005AFF",
              "#005AFF",
              "#005AFF",
              "#F7B737",
              "#F7B737",
              "#B3B3B3",
              "#B3B3B3",
              "#B3B3B3",
              "#B3B3B3",
              "#001135",
              "#E03DCD"
            ]
          },
          "title": "Milestone"
        },
        "shape": {
          "field": "Release Type_Short",
          "type": "nominal",
          "scale": {
            "domain": [
              "MR",
              "FP",
              "SP",
              "UR",
              "MP"
            ],
            "range": [
              "circle",
              "diamond",
              "diamond",
              "diamond",
              "wedge"
            ]
          }
        },
        "stroke": {
          "field": "Status",
          "type": "nominal",
          "scale": {
            "domain": [
              "Approved",
              "Ready for Approval"
            ],
            "range": [
              "#59D241",
              "#E66C37"
            ]
          }
        },
        "tooltip":[
          {
            "field":"Summary",
            "type":"nominal",
            "title":"Summary"
          },
          {
            "field":"Parents Release_Final",
            "type":"nominal",
            "title":"Parent Release"
          },
          {
            "field":"Release Type",
            "type":"nominal",
            "title":"Release Type"
          },
          {
            "field":"Date_Roadmap",
            "type":"temporal",
            "title":"Date"
          }
          ]
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "text",
        "dx": 0,
        "dy": 0,
        "xOffset": 0,
        "yOffset": 17,
        "angle": 0,
        "align": "center",
        "baseline": "bottom",
        "font": "Segoe UI",
        "fontSize": 10,
        "fontStyle": "normal",
        "fontWeight": "normal",
        "color": "black",
        "limit": 0
      },
      "encoding": {
        "text": {"field": "Milestone"},
        "color": {"value": "black"}
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "text",
        "dx": 0,
        "dy": 0,
        "xOffset": 0,
        "yOffset": -5,
        "angle": 0,
        "align": "center",
        "baseline": "bottom",
        "font": "Segoe UI",
        "fontSize": 10,
        "fontStyle": "normal",
        "fontWeight": "normal",
        "color": "black",
        "limit": 0
      },
      "encoding": {
        "text": {
          "field": "Date_Roadmap",
          "type": "temporal",
          "format": "%m/%y"
        },
        "color": {"value": "black"}
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "bar",
        "color": "transparent",
        "tooltip": true
      },
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "field": "Date_Roadmap",
          "timeUnit":"yearmonthdate",
          "type": "nominal",
          "axis": {
            "title": "",
            "format": "%b-%Y",
            "orient": "top",
            "offset": 10,
            "domain": true,
            "ticks": true,
            "tickCount": 20,
            "grid": false,
            "labelPadding": 0,
            "labelAngle": -45,
            "labelOverlap": false,
            "labelSeparation": 0,
            "labelFontSize": 12,
            "labelColor": "black",
            "labelFontWeight": "normal"
          }
        },
        "opacity": {
          "condition": {
            "test": {
              "field": "__selected__",
              "equal": "off"
            },
            "value": 0
          },
          "value": 1
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "encoding": {
    "y": {
      "field": "Parents Release_Final",
      "type": "nominal",
      "axis": {
        "offset": 0,
        "title": null,
        "ticks": true,
        "labelFontSize": 12,
        "minExtent": 70,
        "domain": true,
        "grid": true,
        "gridDash": [4, 4],
        "gridColor": "#C0D8EE",
        "labelColor": "black"
      }
    },
    "x": {
      "field": "Date_Roadmap",
      "scale": {"padding": 25},
      "type": "temporal",
      "axis": {
        "title": "",
        "format": "%b-%Y",
        "ticks":"true",
        "orient": "bottom",
        "offset": 10,
        "domain": true,
        "ticks": true,
        "grid": false,
        "labelExpr":"[timeFormat(datum.value,'%b-%Y')]",
        "labelPadding": 0,
        "labelAngle": -45,
        "labelOverlap": false,
        "labelSeparation": 0,
        "labelFontSize": 12,
        "labelColor": "black",
        "labelFontWeight": "normal"
      },
      "sort": {
        "field": "Date_Roadmap",
        "order": "ascending"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @DavideBacci: Could you please look into this thread.